# Why is **kwargs value in a function decorator different from the value in a function?

Tags: python, decorator, keyword-argument

I'm trying to write a function decorator, that prints arguments, with which a function was called and I noticed one thing. If we create decorator, that simply prints kwargs, it will work. So

```
def counted(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
@counted
def foo(a, b = 4, c = 'blah-blah', *args, **kwargs):
    return

foo(a=1, b=2, c=3, args=[4, 5], kwargs={'d': 6, 'g': 12.9})
```

outputs

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'args': [4, 5], 'kwargs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}}
```

However, if the function is called without decorator, but the arguments are printed inside the function, output differs:

```
#@counted
def foo(a, b = 4, c = 'blah-blah', *args, **kwargs):
print kwargs    #added this line
return
```

Output:

```
{'args': [4, 5], 'kwargs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}}
```

Why is that? Why does print kwargs in a decorator prints first three arguments, but don't in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kwargs` captures any `key=value` parameter that wasn't specifically named in your function signature. `foo` names `a`, `b` and `c` specifically, so those are not captured, but your decorator wrapper names *none*, so everything is captured in `kwargs`. Note that this includes the `args=...` and `kwargs=...` *parameters* you passed into your call.

You need to add `print` to *both* places and you'll see it is not the decorator that is doing anything special here:

```
>>> @counted
... def foo(a, b = 4, c = 'blah-blah', *args, **kwargs):
...     print kwargs
...
>>> foo(a=1, b=2, c=3, args=[4, 5], kwargs={'d': 6, 'g': 12.9})
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'args': [4, 5], 'kwargs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}}
{'args': [4, 5], 'kwargs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}}
```

You also don't print `args`, so you don't see what *positional* arguments are passed along. Let's add some more print statements to show what is really going on:

```
def counted(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'counted args: {!r}'.format(args)
        print 'counted kwargs: {!r}'.format(kwargs)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@counted
def foo(a, b = 4, c = 'blah-blah', *args, **kwargs):
    print 'foo a, b, c: {!r}, {!r}, {!r}'.format(a, b, c)
    print 'foo args: {!r}'.format(args)
    print 'foo kwargs: {!r}'.format(kwargs)
```

Running this you'll get a much better picture:

```
>>> foo(a=1, b=2, c=3, args=[4, 5], kwargs={'d': 6, 'g': 12.9})
counted args: ()
counted kwargs: {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'args': [4, 5], 'kwargs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}}
foo a, b, c: 1, 2, 3
foo args: ()
foo kwargs: {'args': [4, 5], 'kwargs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}}
```

Again, note that both `'args'` and `'kwargs'` are *themselves keyword arguments*; they both end up as keys in the `kwargs` *dictionary*. You could name them anything else and they'll still end up with the new names:

```
>>> foo(a=1, b=2, c=3, spam=[4, 5], eggs={'d': 6, 'g': 12.9})
counted args: ()
counted kwargs: {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'eggs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}, 'spam': [4, 5]}
foo a, b, c: 1, 2, 3
foo args: ()
foo kwargs: {'eggs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}, 'spam': [4, 5]}
```

You didn't specify values for the `*args` and `**kwargs` catch-all variables there, you specified more arbitrary keyword arguments to be captured *in* `kwargs`.

The remaining arguments, `a`, `b` and `c` are 'captured' by the named parameters of the `foo` function. You defined those separately in `foo` so they are assigned to specifically. They are not part of the `wrapper()` definition, so they couldn't be captured there.

Note that you didn't pass any *positional* parameters to the call, so the `*args` variable is *empty*. Pass in some positional arguments instead:

```
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 42, args=[4, 5], kwargs={'d': 6, 'g': 12.9})
counted args: (1, 2, 3, 42)
counted kwargs: {'args': [4, 5], 'kwargs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}}
foo a, b, c: 1, 2, 3
foo args: (42,)
foo kwargs: {'args': [4, 5], 'kwargs': {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}}
```

Now the first 3 values end up in `a`, `b` and `c` still, but the *extra* positional value `42` is still available in `args` in `foo`. In the wrapper, where there were no explicitly named arguments, they *all* ended up in `*args`.

If you expected your `args=[..]` and `kwargs={...}` values to be applied as **separate** arguments, you need to use the same `*` and `**` prefixes when calling **without using the capturing names**:

```
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 42, *[4, 5], **{'d': 6, 'g': 12.9})
counted args: (1, 2, 3, 42, 4, 5)
counted kwargs: {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}
foo a, b, c: 1, 2, 3
foo args: (42, 4, 5)
foo kwargs: {'d': 6, 'g': 12.9}
```

Now `4` and `5` also appear in `args`, and the `'d'` and `'g'` keys appear in the `kwargs` dictionaries directly.